# Data filter by relation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Two Table called- "Users" and "Subscription". Using these controllers I am able to retrieve all users data But I want to only retrieve those users data who has Subscription status = 1 in Subscription column called "status". Please advice me how can I filter my results

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class EmailCampaignController : Controller
    {
        private db_likEntities db = new db_likEntities ();


        // GET: Only Subscribed Users info
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var users = db.Users.Include(u => u.Countries);
            return View(users.ToList());
        }

     }
}
```

Comment: How user and subscription table are related?

Comment: I have stored users foreign key to subscription column called= "UserId" to identify its relation

Comment: So User class have Subscriptions property in your model? Can you share the user ans subscription classes ?

Comment: Yes User has subscription property in model

Comment: This should work. **db.Users.Where(d=>d.Subscriptions.Any(d=>d.Status == "1"))** if you have Subscriptions as a 1-* relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this edit. Hope your users table has that column called `status` otherwise this won't work.

```
public class EmailCampaignController : Controller
{
    private db_likEntities db = new db_likEntities ();


    // GET: Only Subscribed Users info
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //first get all subscriptions whose status is 1
    var trueSubscriptions = db.Subscriptions.Where(s => s.status == 1).ToList();

    //use this variable to filter users by Id
    List<User> users = new List<User>();

    var allUsers = db.Users.Include(u => u.Countries);

    for (int i = 0; i < trueSubscriptions; i++)
    {
        users.Add(allUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == trueSubscriptions[i].UserId));
    }


    return View(users.ToList());
    }

 }
```

For a rather simpler way to achieve this, you would have to edit your models like this.

**Models**

```
public class  User
{
   public int id{get;set;}
   public virtual Subscription subscription{get;set;}
}

public class Subscription
{
   public int id{get;set;}
   public bool status{get;set;}
   public int UserId{get;set;}
}
```

With this approach, you will simply get your subscribed users like this.

```
`var users = db.Users.Include(u => u.Countries)
                        .Where(u => u.subscription.status == true)
                        .ToList();

    return View(users);`
```

Comment: This is a simple and straight forward solution, which will do the job at back end

Comment: Bro, there are two different tables called- "Users" &  "Subscription" and the "status" column in "Subscription" table. got it? So i have to access "Subscription" to filter think. got idea?

Comment: Then am guessing you also have a foreign key of Users table in Subscriptons table, right? If so, tell me so that i can edit this answer.

Comment: Yes correct. I have  foreign key of Users table in Subscriptons table